# Then shalt thou count to [3], no more, no less

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There is a tag on SO called [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3). Just to be clear, this is not an official burninate request, this is simply an inquisition and a discussion question.

Currently *there is no usage guidance for this tag*, and so my questions are these:

1. What exactly does this tag mean, what is it, and what does it apply to?
2. If a tag (such as this one) exists and has no questions, votes, or content, is it worth burninating?

Currently the tag has **91 followers**, which is impressive when the tag has no content whatsoever associated with it.

Any discussion and information on situations such as this one would be much appreciated.

[image: Image of the followers.]

Comment: Also, this is my first meta post. So if there is an obvious reason, please just comment why and I will promptly delete the post.

Comment: Worth noting that the tag bar in the new nav has the tag underlined with a tooltip of "Invalid Tag". However, it does appear in the "Tags" page. I don't think the system even knows what to do with three.

Comment: You're requesting that people go around removing questions from a tag that has no quesitons?  Burnination done I guess *wipes hands*.

Comment: Pro tip: You don't have to add "Edit" to your edits, or post a comment mentioning you edited. The "edited x" link at the bottom of the post and to the left of your username does all that for you. :)

Comment: As I said, this isn't an official burnination request, it's simply me trying to understand why these types of tags still exist in the system at all. It isn't about burninating, more about understand, consolidating and, more importantly, removing future confusion.

Comment: I wasn't expecting some sort of inquiry.

Comment: So the premise of your question is incorrect. There is no tag named "3" with 91 followers. There are 91 people following a non-existent tag. Your question should be "Why are 91 people following a non-existent tag?" The answer to which is "Haven't the faintest", or it could be "How are 91 people following a non-existent tag?", the answer to which would be "Because people are weird, and the system allows such weirdness."

Comment: @yellowantphil and it will probably be recreated directly after. It would be interesting to see if it could actually be applied to a question by a user who does not have the "create new tags" privilege. Regardless, the tag is as non-existent as it can be given the situation.

Comment: -1 because my favorite tag has been deleted due to your request.

Comment: So the tag did not exist? I'm confused. If it didn't exist, how was I able to find it? Or by "exist" do you mean it wasn't able to be _used_, but was able to be _followed_?

Comment: Where did [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3) go? I was prepared to write the exhaustive wiki.

Comment: It is the number of the counting! The number of the counting shall be three! Thou shall not count 4 or 2 except on the way to three. Five is right out.

Comment: @jacknad: It was blown up with the holy hand grenade.

Comment: I saw a guy called messiah the other day, did he create this tag? Because then he wouldn't be living up to his name and would be a naughty boy....

Comment: [3], 2, 1, Burn!

Comment: _"this is simply an inquisition"_ lol +20 lightness points

Comment: I wish I had moderator status so I could add a "3" tag to this question.  Maybe that's why I don't have moderator status...

Comment: That was an unexpected edit.

Comment: I got 20 lightness points? Wow. My life is complete, I can quit SO now. And I only have 88 rep!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If a tag has no questions in it, then it will automatically removed by the system. This is actually the goal of most burninate requests: clear all questions with it so that it gets automatically removed when the job runs.  I'm not quite sure when it runs, though.

New tags with no questions typically mean that a 1.5K user created it and was met by a 2K user rolling their eyes, taking off the tag, and glaring at the tag's creator ominously.

<s>I'm not quite sure how it got 91 followers, though I suspect sockpuppets because that's about 5.35 followers *per hour*. That's essentially impossible.</s>

As explained by Gothdo and yellowphantil in comments:

- Things like CSS3 and Actionscript 3 can be typed with a space, e.g. CSS[space]3.
- The Favorite Tags input accepts spaces and interprets them as breaks between 2 tags.
- A tag does not need to exist to be followed.

Comment: Why would someone create sockpuppets to follow a tag?

Comment: @Gothdo care to offer a different explanation for a pointless tag getting 91 followers in 17 hours?

Comment: @yellowantphil how many lexicographically similar tags can you think of that are that popular?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Why 17 hours?

Comment: @Gothdo because that's how old the tag is.

Comment: @yellowantphil the largest of those tags gets ~20 followers per day on average, though.

Comment: Thanks for those helpful explanations; I've updated the post.

Comment: Perhaps from asp.net-mvc 3, which would be [tag:asp.net-mvc] [tag:3], when typing in the ask questions tags field.

Comment: Ah "A tag does not need to exist to be followed" I get it now. So this tag was not set up or sanctioned by SO, so much as it was created by accidental typos by users, and has been kept alive by the continuous typos. So literally the only reason I found it is because one person typed "css 3" once, and the only reason it wasn't deleted is because others kept doing something similar. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @SalvadorVayshun no, it was created because somebody added it to a question, and had 91 followers from typos over the years.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Got it, but it was because someone mistyped, then it was mistyped over the years.

Comment: I'm going to subscribe to [tag:fnord].

Comment: "A tag does not need to exist to be followed." Hmm. That maybe should be changed...

Comment: A triangle has 3 sides, Illuminatti symbol is a triangle, is this a way of they trying to infiltrate SO ?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel No, it just means half life [3] confirmed!