# Weird tag in job search

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In a job search I see a tag `2`:
[image: tag <code>2</code> example]

If I click on it I can see that it's registered as a tag :

[image: Screenshot]

Can companies apply tags that do not exist in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339512/then-shalt-thou-count-to-3-no-more-no-less

Comment: @code11 In this case `2` is not an existing tag in SO (or I didn't find it in the list)

Comment: Yeah, but its probably because of the same reason, that companies can input whatever they want into that space, like the favorite tags, regardless of whether it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, our sales support team is looking into what the employer's intention was here.

Comment: I think you jinxed it [from here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346084/) - *[...] employers are notoriously bad at using tags correctly[...]* :p

Comment: Haha, I know, cue all the bug reports for bad tags ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, so you confirm that employers are not limited to the list of SO tags? I can understand that, but I wonder if there are tags that employers want to use that are not already in SO.

Comment: @alain.janinm these particular jobs came from our API which has slightly less strict restrictions on tags. We've been discussing whether we should actually restrict jobs to SO tags because there aren't many cases where other tags are actually useful.

Comment: @DeanWard I can imagine for a niche library/tech/discipline that doesn't have/or doesn't warrant an actual SO tag (or is syn'd into more generic tags etc...) it may be useful but generally those I'd have thought would be better in the actual job description itself.

Comment: @JonClements Yes I agree that you can have employers that want to tag a niche techno. But if this niche tag is not found on SO then the employers would have an insight of its lack of popularity here. Hence, informing the employers that there are probably no one that will know the desired techno. On the other hand employers may feel frustrated of not being able to set what they really want...